# Special Email for Tag Email Notifications for each site?

Tags: feature-request

I've selected some of tags of some sites for email notification.

Is there an easy way for changing email for all *tag filter changes notifications* associated with given SE site ? For example : one mail for SO.com another for unix.SE.com ?

I had hard time finding even page listing all *tag filter changes notifications* ?

Am I using proper names of those features ? Please correct post if wrong names used.